# Java Excel Api character codification issue

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I'm developing a java application that reads an Excel file and writes it back to a PDF with some processing inbetween. For reading the spreadsheet I'm using the excellent jExcelApi library, and this is a code excerpt:

```
workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(fullName));

Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

this.data.customer_name = sheet.getCell("B8").getContents();
```

Everything works as expected, but I realized that the output is different on the production machine than on the development. It has to do with character encoding. Here's an example of the output file in both computers:

```
|-------------|-------------|
| Development | Production  |
|-------------|-------------|
| Söderkvist  | S��derkvist |
| Østnes      | ��stnes     |
| Müller      | M��ller     |
|-------------|-------------|
```

The machines have Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04 and, although they're not exactly identical, I'm using the same JRE in  both. I've been browsing the jExcelApi documentation and I found a `WorkbookSettings` class with method for getting/setting the character encoding, but I don't know how to get the actual XLS source file encoding. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hopeful tip: The .xlsx file format defines this problem out of existence.

Comment: Hi, the XLS are provided by an external operator so I can't change its format. Anyway, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prod is ASCII
dev is UTF-8

```
WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
workbookSettings.setEncoding( "UTF-8" );
Workbook.getWorkbook( theFile, workbookSettings );
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean bash encoding? I've checked it on both machines running `echo $LANG`  and it's 'es_ES.UTF-8'. Just in case, running `file` on the source Excel file says that its code page is 1252.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I've been out of the office and couldn't test it. I've tried it now and it works perfectly, now all the characters are the right ones, thanks!